# Use the same IDB2 connection between forms

Tags: c#, connection

Either this is so simple that no one is asking about it, or not many people are trying to do this so I am unable to find any kind of good results in a google query.  Basically, my main form is creating an IDB2 connection to an i-series (AS400) mainframe:

```
Connection con = new Connection();
con.Open(connectionString, userName, userPassword, 0);
```

The main form can use this connection fine.  I have another form that displays records in an internal SQL database on the PC, but this form also needs to access the AS400.  I added an entry parameter of IDB2connection, and when the form first initializes the connection state is open.  However, when I click on a button on the form and enter into that new subroutine, the connection is null.  In order to keep the connection open at all times, do I need to make it public or something?  I could put all the code to re-open a new connection in this form, but it seems kind of clunky.  Any ideas of how to share the open connection between forms?

New form:

```
private iDB2Connection conn;

public frmFileDatabase(iDB2Connection conn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // conn is null at this point
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private iDB2Connection conn;

public frmFileDatabase(iDB2Connection _conn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conn = _conn;
    }

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you can use the connection
    }
```

you need to assign the parameter to your private variable,
this might help you

Comment: I figured it was something simple and stupid.  Thanks for shining the light on my crazy world.  :)